# error: cannot find symbol java.util.Properties

Tags: java, codenameone

i have a problem in netbeans or my project i don't know what it is exactly but i have this error when i try to work with properties and it's not about code i'm sure of it
here is an image of the error

[Could not find symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7YKn.png)

Comment: Please publish build.xml and source code class

Answer (score 0):

We don't support the [full Java API](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/why-we-dont-support-the-full-java-api.html) and this API isn't supported either. However, we have our own `Properties` implementation in `com.codename1.io` see the [JavaDocs](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/).

Comment: I solved the problem by adding a jar that contains that class to send an email I used an external Javax mail API

Comment: That will fail on the device. You can't change the classpath of a Codename One application